# Validation of viewstate MAC failed caused due to Application Pool Idle Timeout

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

i had bought a web domain online where i am hosting asp.net *website's/web-application's*.

Many a times I am facing an error:

```
Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster......
```

After a long research i had found that the error occurs due to *"Application Pool Idle Timeout"*.

By default an app-pool will recycle every 5 minutes. If this recycle happened while a user is busy on the site and send post back to the server, the server no longer recognizes the session/viewstate and rejects what is being posted back.

My "Application Pool Idle Timeout" value is around **5 min.** which is too short.

i had contacted the domain person to change the timeout period but they refused to do so saying its same for all and cant be changed.

I had googled for other solutions and found the below solutions:

1. Setting the EnableViewStateMAC property to false (Not good w.r.t. security reasons).
2. Provide your own validation and decryption keys "" (Doesn't work).

Please provide me a better solution ASAP.

Or Should I change the domain manager (like godaddy.com).

Answer (score -1):

I have seen and resolved this issue in past. This issue majorly comes when you host application on Web Farm or web Cluster.

When a page is rendered, its view state is encrypted on server and sent to client. When page is posted back, this view state data is decrypted on server to get the state of the page. For Encryption and decryption of viewState server uses some keys, which if not provided in Maching.config files, are generated on the fly by server.

If you are on a single server hosting environment, these keys might get recycled. But on a Web Farm or Web Cluster, if these keys are generated at random then they are different for every server, and a request from one server can be posted back to another server that has different set of key and where it fails.

Solution to this is Adding MachineKey entries to all the server's Machine.Config files, or to your application's web.config files so that each server uses same keys for encryption and decryption of view state.